# Referencing to a subsection with numbers and not the subsection name

Tags: cross-referencing

Assume

```
 \section{first}
   \subsection{first-1} 
   \label{marker}
 \section{MySecondSection}
 In section ~\nameref{marker} we defined...
```

In the output I see:

```
In section first-1 we defined...
```

However I want the section number. Like:

```
In section 1.1 we defined...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use plain `\ref` to get the number.

There is some information about how to use references [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Sections).